# Steady state error in a digital control system

Tags: control-theory

Suppose we have the following open loop transfer function in a discrete system:
\begin{equation}
G(z) = \frac{0.1z+0.15}{(z-1)(z-0.1)}
\end{equation}
Under the unity negative feedback, we know that closed loop transfer fucntion becomes:
\begin{equation}
G_c(z) = \frac{G(z)}{1+G(z)} = \frac{z+1.5}{z^2-z+0.25}
\end{equation}

Now, we want to find the steady state error when the input is unit ramp.
\begin{equation}
e_{ss} = lim_{z -> 1} [(1-z^{-1})\frac{1}{1+G(z)}R(z)]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R(z) = \frac{Tz^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
e_{ss} &= lim_{z -> 1} [(1-z^{-1})\frac{1}{1+G(z)}\frac{Tz^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})^2}] \\
&= lim_{z -> 1}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{0.1z+0.15}{(z-1)(z-0.1)}}\frac{Tz^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} \\
&= \frac{(z-1)(z-0.1)}{(z-1)(z-0.1)+0.1z+0.15}\frac{Tz^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} \\ 
&= \frac{(z-1)(z-0.1)z^{-1}}{z^{-1}[(z-1)(z-0.1)+0.1z+0.15]}\frac{Tz^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}} \\
&= \frac{(z-0.1)}{[(z-1)(z-0.1)+0.1z+0.15]}T \\
&= \frac{0.9}{0.25} T
\end{align*}
As shown above the state error is constant.
When I try to test this result in MATLAB, however, the output seems to not be able to follow the input. MATLAB script which I use as follows:

```
num = [0 1 1.5]
den = [1 -1 0.25]
r = 0:100
c = filter(num,den,r)
```

Can somebody tell what's wrong in here?
[image: Response to unit ramp]

Comment: You are plotting ramp response of $G(z)/(1+G(z))$ instead of $1/(1+G(z))$.

Comment: Yes, why would you use $1/(1+G(z))$? $C(z)/R(z)$ is $G(z)/(1+G(z))$

Comment: For the same reason you used that transfer function for $e_{ss}$. Namely, $G(z)/(1+G(z))$ is the closedloop transfer function from reference to output. However, here one is interested not in the output but in the error, whose transfer function is given by $1-G(z)/(1+G(z))=1/(1+G(z))$.

Comment: $e(t) = c(t) - r(t)$. In the graph above, I plot the reference input r(t) and the output c(t). What I expect is as time goes on, the difference between two lines converge to some constant value. The difference between the two lines already gives the error signal.

Comment: just spotted that that is because you are missing a factor 1/10 for $G_c(z)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With the correct form of the closed loop transfer function, I verified the correct result now. Thank you for your time @KwinvanderVeen